# PowerShell - PnP - Microsoft Groups - Get Guest access setting AllowToAddGuests

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft365, pnp.powershell

I'm using the AzureADPreview module to find out if a group has guest access allowed.  This is working fine and returns true/false, script shown below:

```
$groupSettings = Get-AzureADObjectSetting -TargetType Groups -TargetObjectId $groupId
$guestAccessEnabled = ($groupSettings["AllowToAddGuests"])
Write-Host($guestAccessEnabled)
```

I'm now trying to do the same but using the PnP.PowerShell module but I can't seem to get a true/false result.  The following returns 'PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Model.Microsoft365GroupSettingItemValues' and I'm not sure how to expand out this object to get the 'AllowToAddGuests' setting.

```
$groupSettings = Get-PnPMicrosoft365GroupSettings -Identity $groupId 
Write-Host($groupSettings.Values)
```

I'm pretty sure this is an issue with how I'm going about accessing the object, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter `$groupSettings.Values` and find an item with `Name` that equals `AllowToAddGuests`.

```
$groupSettings = Get-PnPMicrosoft365GroupSettings -Identity $groupId 
$allowToAddGuests = $groupSettings.Values | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'AllowToAddGuests'}
Write-Host($allowToAddGuests.Value)
```